TypeScript Custom Error Class: Modified Error Message Not Being Displayed
I'm having trouble with a custom error class in TypeScript where the modified error message does not display correctly, I just get the error message returned from the API call.
My customError classs--
export class CustomError extends Error {
    cod:string;
    constructor(cod:string , message: string){
        super(message);
        this.cod = cod;
        Object.setPrototypeOf(this , new.target.prototype);

        if (Error.captureStackTrace) {
            Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor);
        }
    }
}

The class inheriting--
import { CustomError } from "./CustomError";

export class CityNotFoundError extends CustomError {
    constructor(cod:string , message: string){
        const errMsg:string = message + " :The city you provided was not found,Please verify"
        super(cod,errMsg);
    }
}

The error handler function.
import { CityNotFoundError } from "../Errors/CityNotFoundError";
export function ErrorHandler(cod: string , message: string){
    switch(cod){
        case '404':
            const errMsg:string = message + " :The city you provided was not found,Please verify"
            return new CityNotFoundError(cod,errMsg);
    }
}

This is the function
app.get('/',async (req:Request,res:Response) =>{
    await fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={location}&&appid={API_KEY}`).
    then(async(response) =>{ 
        const data = await response.json();
        console.log(data)
        res.json(data);
    }).
        catch(async(err) =>{
            const error = ErrorHandler(err.cod , err.message)!;
            console.error(error.stack);
            res.status(500).json({
                code: error.cod,
                message: error.message,
            });
        })
})

I get this error { cod: '404', message: 'city not found' }
but I want this..
{ cod: '404', message: 'city not found: :The city you provided was not found,Please verify' }
What might be causing the issue where the error message is not modified as expected? How can I ensure that the additional context I add in the CityNotFoundError constructor is included in the error message when it is logged?

Where exactly are you getting that error? Are you certain that ErrorHandler is even called? There is a lot of problems not with your Error subclassing but rather with your async fetch code

@Bergi Yes I found where the problem was, I just had to check the response, I get back from the API call and throw error based on the status code. But can you please tell me if there's anything else that is problematic in the code, or maybe how to improve it maybe.Would like to get some feedback, I am kind of new to this.

Yes, not checking the response is the main problem; you may want to post an answer if you did solve this. But I would also recommend not to mix await with .then(…) syntax.

I found the issue,I just had to check the response json for an unsuccessful response and then throw the error.
fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={Location}&&appid={API_KEY}`).
then(async(response) =>{ 
    if(!response.ok){
        const errData = await response.json();
        console.log(errData)
        throw ErrorHandler(errData.cod,errData.message);
    }
    const data = await response.json();
    res.json(output);

